# cbb tag should be merged with consensus-by-bet?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I tried the merge and didn't have enough votes for the tags.  It seems obvious that we should merge them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[consensus-by-bet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consensus-by-bet) or [consensus-by-block](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consensus-by-block)?

There are only two questions affected. I vote to remove the short form.

Comment: "by bet".  I edited away the "CBB" that was in the title of this question http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152/what-is-consensus-by-bet to make it clearer